# powerpoint vba creating and saving slides

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

When I call each module separately everything works fine... but when I call them from the ***MAIN*** module the text does not shrink on overflow on the saved slides. Can you please help to find a way to fix this

```
Sub MAIN()

Call Module1.CreateSlides
Call Module2.SaveSlides

End Sub
```

[***Module1***]

```
Sub CreateSlides()

'Open the Excel workbook. Change the filename here.
Dim OWB As New Excel.Workbook
Set OWB = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\B\Books\TXT.xlsx")

'Grab the first Worksheet in the Workbook
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Set WS = OWB.Worksheets(1)

'Loop through each used row in Column A
For i = 1 To WS.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    'Copy the first slide and paste at the end of the presentation
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Copy
    ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste (ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1)

    'Change the text of the first text box on the slide.
    ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = WS.Cells(i, 1).Value
    ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = WS.Cells(i, 2).Value
    ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = WS.Cells(i, 3).Value
 Next

'Close Excel
ActiveWorkbook.Close

'Delete presentation
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Delete

End Sub
```

[**Module2**]

```
Sub SaveSlides ()

'Save slides as png
Dim sImagePath As String
Dim sImageName As String
Dim oSlide As Slide '* Slide Object

On Error GoTo Err_ImageSave

sImagePath = "C:\"
For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    sImageName = oSlide.SlideNumber & ".png"
    oSlide.Export sImagePath & sImageName, "PNG"
Next oSlide

Err_ImageSave:
If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Description
End If

'Delete all slides
Dim Pre As Presentation
Set Pre = ActivePresentation
Dim x As Long
For x = Pre.Slides.Count To 1 Step -1
    Pre.Slides(x).Delete
Next x

'Add New slide
Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1)
Set Sld = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(1, pptLayout)
Sld.Design = ActivePresentation.Designs(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: You should use breakpoints to see where the execution goes, and if that doesn't show you the cause of the problem (unlikely) you should post the findings of that debugging.

Comment: What line are you getting your error ?

Comment: I tried debugging but it does not detect any errors on the code itself. If I press the run button for each module there are no problems at all. I have a long list of modules and I need to call them. Can you please check in case I am missing something. The excel file has three columns of long text that will need to be shrinked on overflow

Comment: there is no need to use `Call Module1.CreateSlides`, you can use `Call CreateSlides`

Comment: Shai Rado I am calling from another module not from within

Comment: Both modules work fine when I call them separately. When I combine them or call them together.. the result is not the same. The slides are created and saved ....but on the saved png slides, the text overflows and is not shrinked. That does not happen when I call module2 without module1. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixup module to be applied separately

```
Sub FixUp()

Dim Obj1 As Object
Set Obj1 = CreateObject("powerpoint.application")
Obj1.Presentations.Open FileName:="C:\B\name.pptm"

    Dim pptSlide As Slide
    Dim pptShape as Shape
    'Set pptSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    For Each pptSlide in ActivePresentation.Slides
      'With pptSlide.Shapes(1)
       For Each pptShape in pptSlide.Shapes
          With pptShape
          If .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Count > 1 Then
              .TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape
          End If
          End With '  pptShape
       Next  ' pptShape
      End With
    Next   ' Slide
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned "the text does not shrink on overflow on the saved slides". What text are you referring to? There are no lines that are setting the following property in your code so any on-slide objects should be following the properties of those objects in your Slide Master (and associated Custom Layouts).

```
Sld.Shapes(x).TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText
```

Try using the above line to explicitly set the fit option as required. Modified sub:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateSlides()

'Open the Excel workbook. Change the filename here.
Dim OWB As New Excel.Workbook
Set OWB = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\B\Books\TXT.xlsx")
Dim i As Long

'Grab the first Worksheet in the Workbook
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Set WS = OWB.Worksheets(1)

'Loop through each used row in Column A
For i = 1 To WS.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
  With ActivePresentation
    'Copy the first slide and paste at the end of the presentation
    .Slides(1).Copy
    .Slides.Paste (.Slides.Count + 1)

    'Change the text of the first text box on the slide.
    With .Slides(.Slides.Count).Shapes(1).TextFrame2
      .AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText
      .WordWrap = msoTrue
      .TextRange.Text = WS.Cells(i, 1).Value
    End With
    With .Slides(.Slides.Count).Shapes(2).TextFrame2
      .AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText
      .WordWrap = msoTrue
      .TextRange.Text = WS.Cells(i, 2).Value
    End With
    With .Slides(.Slides.Count).Shapes(3).TextFrame2
      .AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText
      .WordWrap = msoTrue
      .TextRange.Text = WS.Cells(i, 3).Value
    End With
  End With
 Next

'Close Excel
ActiveWorkbook.Close

'Delete presentation
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi JamieG. Thank you for your reply. On the slide master I have formated text to shrink on overflow. I tried your modified sub but the text on the created slides overflows on top of each other. Just try to increase the font on slidemaster or make the text on excel very long. The code I had for module1 does not have that problem. The slides are created and saved when modules are run separately and the text does not overflow. But when I run them together, then the saved slides do not produce the same result, the text on each slide runs on top of each other and does not shrink as it should

Comment: .AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape

Comment: I replaced:   .AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText       with: .AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape.  When I run create module separately it shrinks... but when I call both modules to createslide and to saveslide I have the same problem. I tried to combine both subs on the same module and still receive the same result. Is there a code to run the second module auto...like you would manually with F5 or run button.. I have tried both "call" and "application run"

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in PowerPoint.  I've run into the same problem myself.

If you can run the whole main batch of code, then separately run another small module to "tidy up" the text, you can fix this.

Somewhere in the main code, tag each shape that holds text (or perhaps just the ones set to shrink on overflow).  For example, if you had a reference to the shape in oSh:

```
oSh.Tags.Add "H", cStr(oSh.Height)
oSh.Tags.Add "W", cStr(oSh.Width)
```

Now the shape is tagged with the size it SHOULD be.  When your main code pours text into it, the size will reset (incorrectly... there's the bug).

So later, separately, you run code that

```
' Looks at each shape on each slide and
' if it's tagged, reset the size to the
' size indicated by the tags:
If Len(oSh.Tags("H")) > 0 Then
   oSh.Height = cSng(oSh.Tags("H")
   oSh.Width = cSng(oSh.Tags("W")
End if
```

Comment: Hi Steve Rindsberg I posted the changes as an answer because the code was to long to post here. Can you please check and let me know if I am doing something wrong, because I am getting the same result.

Comment: You missed the part about "So later, separately, you run code that..."   You can't run the fixup routine as part of your main code.  You run it separately. After all your other code has run and you're back to looking at the results.  Stupid?  Yes.  Bug workarounds often are like that. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your help I have followed your suggestion and figured out the way to workaround it. (posted the code as an answer)

Comment: I have noticed that the "tidy up" sub only correct the top slides on the presentation, the last ones remain unchanged. Is there a way to correct this?